# Comedy where a guy glues a dog to his hand while hiding in closet

Tags: identify-this-movie, comedy

This film is old, might even be from the eighties.

The only scene I can remember is that the main male character, who I seem to remember being some sort of detective or PI was in a woman's room when she came home.  He hid in her closet, where there was a tube of superglue on the floor.  Her little yappy terrier dog ran up and started barking at the closet doors (I think they were the louvered folding style).  He reached out and grabbed the dog and pulled it into the closet to quiet it, accidentally gluing it to his hand.

I thought this was a Chevy Chase movie, and rewatched *Fletch* just to see if that was it, but no luck. Does this sound familiar to anyone?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like Blake Edwards' [The Man Who Loved Women](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0085891/combined) with Burt Reynolds and Julie Andrews from 1983.

> This is the tale of a sculptor named David who has a major womanizing problem. He goes to seek help from a psychiatrist, Marianna, to cure him of his obsession with women. His story of sexual and romantic exploits with the ladies is told by Marianna.

In one scene, he hides in the closet when a woman's (I think Kim Basinger)  husband comes home, and somehow gets his hand glued to a dog. IIRC, he then escapes with the dog still glued to him. It's a remake of a [French film from 1977](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Man_Who_Loved_Women_(1977_film)). Here's the trailer: